# Why Mathematica doesn't return a column? Kronecker product thinks it's a row, when it should be a column

Tags: list-manipulation

I wanted to create the following matrix by using block partition of matrices.

$\left[\begin{array}{c}
I_D \otimes \text{Col}(K,1)\\
\vdots\\
I_D \otimes \text{Col}(K,T)
\end{array}\right]$

Let

```
D=2
B = {{1, 1}, {1, 4}}
```

I used at first this function:

```
mat[T_, K_] := 
  ArrayFlatten[
   Table[KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2], K[[;; , i]]], {i, 1, 
     T}]];
```

The problem with this function is that the result has some () where they shouldn't be...

We can see that from `mat[2, B] // MatrixForm`

I have this function which solves the problem

```
mat2[T_, K_] := 
  Transpose[
   ArrayFlatten[{Table[
      KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2], K[[;; , i]]], {i, 1, 
       T}]}]];
```

When I do `mat[2, B] // MatrixForm` , I clearly see that the extra () have disappeared.

I think the problem starts with `K[[;; , i]]]` which returns a list which the kronecker thinks its a row, when I wanted a column...

Is there a way for `K[[;; , i]]]` to return a column?

Comment: Both `mat[;;, 1]]` and `mat[[1, ;;]]` return a one-dimensional array (assuming that `mat` is a two-dimensional array). "Row" and "column" make no sense in this context. `{1, 2, 3}` is a vector. `{{1, 2, 3}}` and `{{1},{2},{3}}` are matrices, not vectors (even though they are sometimes confusingly referred to as row-vector and column-vector). Some other systems, such as MATLAB, do not support vectors at all, and will *always* return the matrix, thus they force the "row/column vector" distinction. Mathematica does not.

Comment: `D` has built-in meanings. Try to avoid starting one's own namings with capital letters in *Mathematica*.

Comment: @Szabolcs but mathematically, the kronecker product will give a different matrix, with different dimensions...

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Thanks I forgot that. ;)

Comment: the obvious answer to the last question is `Transpose[{K[[;;,i]]}]`; you could also try `ArrayFlatten[{KroneckerProduct[iN, Transpose[{#}]]} & /@ Transpose[B]]` as an alternative, where `iN=IdentityMatrix[n]`

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks, that looks nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
newmat[idim_Integer, oldmat_?MatrixQ] :=
  Catenate[Transpose[KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[idim], #]] &
    /@ Transpose@oldmat]
```